# Display latitude and Longitude from MapBox API using Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mapbox-gl-js

I am Unable to Display latitude and Longitude on the webpage, when I searched with city/state,
Need to get those values and display on the browser, Should I need to change anything in the code
Please help me in this . Thanks in advance

Here is my code :

```
import React,{useState} from 'react'

const useInput = (initialvalue) => {
    const [value, setvalue] = useState(initialvalue);

    const handleChange = async (event) =>{
        setvalue(event.target.value);
      try{
      const endPoint = `Map Box API Goes here`
      const response =  await fetch(endPoint); 
      const results =   await response.json();
      console.log(results);
      } catch(error){
          console.log(error)
      }
  }
  
    return {
      value,
      onChange: handleChange,
      setvalue
    };
}

export default useInput
```

[image: Here you can find the coordinates, I need to display that on broswer]

here is the input search box

```
import React,{useState} from 'react';
import useInput from '../Mapboxgeocoding/useInput';

const MapInput = () => {
    const address = useInput("");
  return (
    <div>
        <input placeholder='address' {...address} />
       
    </div>
  )
}

export default MapInput
```

Comment: `const [long, lat] = results.features[0].geometry.coordinates;` should do it.

Comment: @ChrisG  Yes Thank you for your answer... Can you give me a solution for putting  whole Input field in one file  , rather than creating another file for that Input field....

Comment: A useInput hook is a nice idea so I've used it here (rewritten): https://codesandbox.io/s/red-bash-nosq5y?file=/src/App.js I moved the API requests outside though. You should also use debouncing so not every keypresses triggers an api request.

Comment: @ChrisG I am getting this error, If I use the code in Sandbox given by you...
react-refresh-runtime.development.js:596 Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at react-refresh-runtime.development.js:596:1
    at useInput (useInput.js:3:1)

Comment: Although in mapbox API I am passing one string ...
 const handleChange = async (event) =>{
        setvalue(event.target.value);

 const endPoint=`https://api.mapbox.com/geocoding/v5/mapbox.places/${event.target.value}.json?
 const response =  await fetch(endPoint); 
const results =   await response.json();
}

Comment: This error doesn't occur in my sandbox so you made a mistake when implementing my code. The cause is usually a useEffect that changes one of its own dependencies, that leads to an infinite loop. Or having a function call inside your JSX that changes state. A common mistake is to pass a function *call* to `onChange` instead of a function.